# I copied an SQL folder that contains database info and I would like to add it to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. How Do I do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not very familiar with databases, but I have a task where an entire database folder was backed up and copied to a drive on my computer. I have SQL Server installed and Microsoft SQL Server opened. How do I use this folder and its contents as a database?

The folder has the following subfolders

SQL Server -> Backup, binn, DATA, FTData, Install, Jobs, Log, Upgrade and two files: sql_engine_core_inst_keyfile.dll, sql_fulltext_keyfile.dll

Comment: Are there things like .mdf files under DATA, .ldf files under Log?

Comment: `Backup` is the default folder for database backup (usually .bak files). If you have a backup file, you could try to [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-backup-using-ssms) it. `DATA` is the default folder for database files (.mdf, .ndf, .ldf files). If you only have those, you could try to [attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database) the database.

Comment: yes, ldf and mdf files in data

Comment: @Sander beat me to it.  Unless there is encryption involved you should be able to either restore from a backup file or attach.  But it also assumes that you are running the same version and edition of SQL Server as what the folder was copied from.

Answer (score 0):

For each **.ldf+.mdf** file sets you have you can restore a database using the following sql. You cannot create the databases in bulk and will have to do them one at a time if you have multiple.

For each .ldf + .mdf combo you have update the `dbname` and the two `filenames`

```
create database dbname

on

(   

Filename= 'path where you copied .mdf data file',   

Filename ='path where you copied .ldf log file'

)
```